# change array key while for each

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have array like this an want to change this as bellow array.
 how can I change It? Am I want to use foreach for this?
 I just want to modify key.
 Key must be same as all the sub arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [H12] => 100.00
            [I12] => 100.00
            [G12] => 2017-12-20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [H12] => 100.00
            [I12] => 100.00
            [G12] => 2017-12-20
        )
```

and I want to change this array as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [H] => 100.00
            [I] => 100.00
            [G] => 2017-12-20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [H] => 100.00
            [I] => 100.00
            [G] => 2017-12-20
        )
```

Comment: Yes, you can change it with `foreach`. Now write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Use foreach loop and [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp) function

```
$main_arr = //YOUR CURRENT ARRAY

for ($i = 0; $i < count($main_arr); $i++){
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach($main_arr[$i] as $key => $value){
        $new_arr[substr($key, 0, 1)] = $value;
    }
    $main_arr[$i] = $new_arr;
}
```